# Magento 1.7 login does not work - no message

Tags: php, magento, cookies, authentication

I copied an production magento shop to my dev-server.

Production: PHP 5.3
Dev-Server: PHP 5.4.

- On my dev-server i installed the php5.4 patch provided by magento.
- I changed in the Database the cookie settings, and the base url(s) to the new dev domain (something.development.th).
- i cleared the cache & session folder in the /var folder.
- i cleared my local cache and cookies ( also incognito mode and other browsers)
- chmod to 777 to all files

If i want to login with bad credentials - there is an error message
If i login with the correct credentials - there is NO message.

I can´t figure it out. the current suggestions i found here and on google are the steps i already described.

EDIT: Happens on Admin Login & Customer Login

EDIT: Cookie Settings are:

```
web/cookie/cookie_domain -> something.development.th 
web/cookie/cookie_httponly -> 1 ( was 0, too )
web/cookie/cookie_path -> /
```

Comment: This is usually a cookie problem. What did you set your cookie settings to?

Comment: i changed topic & text. also happens to customer login.

Comment: settings are: 
web/cookie/cookie_domain -> something.development.th ||
web/cookie/cookie_httponly -> 1  ||
web/cookie/cookie_path -> /

Comment: Have you tried removing all of the cookie settings from the database, leaving them as the default values? For example, try setting the cookie domain to NULL.

Comment: just did it and gone into incognito - same result

Comment: Hm, something must definitely be wrong with the cookies or your session storage. Open your browser's cookie inspector and look at the `adminhtml` cookie. Is it created? Is the domain correct? Does its value correspond to a valid session in `var/session` (the cookie value should match the file name of the session storage file)?

Comment: yes, it is created, yes it correspond to a valid session. But what i recognized is that the Expires / Max-Age Date is in the past.

Comment: ok, i fixed a try before, now there is just "Session" in the Expires / Max Age tab -still no login

Comment: i don´t know if its normal: the session file is empty.

Comment: Is the disk full?  Has var/session got the correct permissions? (assuming you have the sessions saved to file rather than database in app/etc/local.xml - `<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>` )

Comment: The disk has enough free space, the permissions are more then they need (777) and yes, i save the session into files.

Comment: Try to replace the .htaccess file and index.php file with default Magento's files.Give 777 permission to var folder. If does not work reply back

Comment: @Muk: i replaced it, set the permissions to 777 - no login. session file created but empty

Comment: @develth , If you are using Linux,Please check SELinux is in permissive mode or not?

Comment: @Muk: i use debian wheezy, SELinux is not enabled.